# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

estoy teniendo el siguiente error al ejecutar un proyecto Maven con spring boot, este es un microservicio sera encardo de hacer login y realizara un crud en una base de datos MySQL, y sera encargado de generar y validar un JSON Web Token.

Al ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run 

    your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2023-11-07T20:12:06.371-05:00 ERROR 8480 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getXmlMappingBinderAccess(MetadataSources.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
```

No cuento con una clase especifica que realice importación de jakarta.xml.bind, pero consultando encuentro que el error se soluciona haciendo  importación de una versión más actualizada, importe la versión 4.0.0 de jakarta.xml.bind pero el error persiste.

El error aparecion luego de hacer uso de ResponseEntity, HttpStatus, BCryptPasswordEncoder, GrantedAuthority. Pero no logro determinar la raiz del problema.

Este es mi archivo pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.crud</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRUD-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CRUD-java</name>
    <description>Crud project for Spring Boot java</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Proyecto JW token-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON WEB TOKEN -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency-->
        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```